# Constant sum of exradii

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Can you prove or disprove the following claim:

> **Claim**. Given any [cyclic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#:%7E:text=In%20Euclidean%20geometry%2C%20a%20cyclic,are%20said%20to%20be%20concyclic.) $ABCD$. Consider a triangle defined by any triple of the vertices of quadrilateral. Define exradius of the triangle's excircle that touches side of the quadrilateral as outer exradius, and exradius of the triangle's excircle that touches a diagonal of the quadrilateral as inner exradius. Then, no matter how one triangulates a quadrilateral $ABCD$, the sum of outer exradii of triangles is constant.

[image]
[image]

Let us denote exradii of triangle $\triangle ABC$ - $r_1,r_2,r_3$ , exradii of triangle $\triangle ACD$ - $r_4,r_5,r_6$ , exradii of triangle $\triangle ABD$ - $r_7,r_8,r_9$ and exradii of triangle $\triangle BCD$ - $r_{10},r_{11},r_{12}$ , where $r_3,r_6,r_9,r_{12}$ are inner exradii. Using the [Japanese theorem for cyclic polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_theorem_for_cyclic_polygons#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20the%20Japanese%20theorem,inradii%20of%20triangles%20is%20constant.&text=Conversely%2C%20if%20the%20sum%20of,it%20is%20a%20Sangaku%20problem.) and identity $r_a+r_b+r_c=4R+r$ ,where $r_a,r_b,r_c$ are exradii, $R$ - circumradius and $r$ - inradius one can show that: $r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4+r_5+r_6=r_7+r_8+r_9+r_{10}+r_{11}+r_{12}$ . Now, in order to finish the proof I need to  show that: $r_3+r_6=r_9+r_{12}$  and I don't know how to do that. Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: By not drawing the internal circles you leave it to the reader to understand what you mean - many will be discouraged by such "laziness" to attempt helping you.

Comment: @Moti I didn't want to overload the drawings.

Comment: It would avoid mis interpretations. May be by using area equations of the triangles you may derive a solution. Also note that the multiplications of of distances to sides and diagonals are equal.

Comment: It's not too difficult to show that the constant sum is twice the circumdiameter. More finely, in convex cyclic $\square ACBC'$, focus on $\triangle ABC$. Exradii $r_A$ and $r_B$i of excircles opposite $A$ and $B$ satisfy $r_A+r_B=2|DM|$, where $M$ is the mdpt of $\overline{AB}$, and $D$ is where the diameter through $M$ meets the circle; that is, $r_A+r_B$ is twice the "height" of $\stackrel{\frown}{ACB}$. Likewise, the sum of the exradii in $\triangle ABC'$ is twice the "height" of $\stackrel{\frown}{AC'B}$. The two "heights" make a diameter, so the four-exradius sum is twice that diameter.

Comment: Isn't    r3+r6=r9+r12 a straightforward result of the Japanese Theorem since ABCD is a Cyclic Polygon?

Comment: @Moti No it isn't, because $r_3,r_6,r_9$ are exradii, not inradii.

Comment: Could this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry help you? Converting your problem into something close to the Japanese Theorem case?

Comment: @Moti Perhaps.Thanks.